# New error codes during scratch org creation

Tags: error-messages, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I have read the SignUpRequest page (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_signuprequest.htm#stq=VR-0003&stp=1) but I did not find the following error codes.

I want to be able to give an explanation of the following error codes to my end users. I have tried to create a scratch org with the `release` option set to `previous` from an org that isn't preview. I have then received an error code `X-0002`. I assume this meant that I can not create a scratch org with `release` set to `previous` if the org isn't a preview one. I did expect an error to occur but I could not find information about this error code anywhere online.

I have also tried to create a scratch org from a `preview org` with the `release` option set to `preview` and that returned error code `VR-0003`. In that case I am assuming that it indicates that you can't use the preview option from an already preview org.

Could you please give me more information about those error codes or point to the right place where I can find this information?

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check if your `dev hub` is a pre-release org. If so, that might be the problem. Please use a non-pre-release org as your `dev hub`, and set the scratch org `release` to `preview`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am interested in finding out more about the error codes I have listed above so I can provide better error handling for my end users. I would like to know if these error codes that I encountered (`X-0002` and `VR-0003`) are specific to the release property errors, so that I can confidently suggest the correct solution to my end users whenever they appear.